# eclipse and boost unit_test_framework failing syntax check using c++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, unit-testing, boost

i have the following Problem.
I started to use the boost library version 1.40, for unit testing. 
Since some other people working on the project and not all of them are using eclipse, the program has to be compilable with a makefile. So we used cmake to generate one. 
The good thing is, the test is building and working perfectly fine.

But the problem is, when using eclipse (created a c++ makefile project), it complains about several syntax errors (in the sourcecode view). 
Something like:
    `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{ some code }`     
will be detected as a syntax error by eclipse. It is really annoying having all these error messages in the IDE. Since after the first line nearly every line in the `some code` block is marked as having syntax errors as well.
So here is what i tried already:

- I added    `/usr/include/boost/`     to the GNU C++ path options. (properties->C/C++ General->Path and Symbols->Path). This works normally for other external libs that are included by FindPkgConfig in the cmake file. So that the auto completion in eclipse can find the correct classes and function names.
- Same way included     `/usr/include/boost/test/`    directly.
- Adding     `/usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.40.0`    to the Libraries list.
- Adding    `/usr/lib`     to the Library Paths.

So anyone has a hint how to teach eclipse that the syntax of the boost Macros is correct??

**Update**:
I forgot:
System is Linux and Eclipse Version is 3.6.1, CDT Version is:
Version: 1.0.0.201009141542
Build id: 201009141542

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution but maybe a hint.
I had a similar setup and it worked perfectly until... 
the only relevant change I remember is that I changed the name of a test suite.
So (probably) after that, the syntax highlighting went crazy.
I tried indexing and refreshing but it didn't help.
I can't even see the macro expansion because the syntax error prevents it from popping up.

My guess is — still — some indexing issue, because it worked before and I didn't change any include paths. It compiles without problems, but it's urinating these yellow syntax error markers all over the document, which is really, really annoying.

However, it's probably not a path issue because it worked for me before.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this myself using Eclipse Helios, and it does indeed work for me...

Shouldnt you add `/usr/include` and not `/usr/include/boost`, since `boost` is part of the include path used in your program?

For example `<boost/unit_test.hpp>` is simply `<unit_test.hpp>` if you include the boost folder aswell..

This is what I have added under GNU c++ include directories:

```
/usr/local/include //this is where I store the boost folder
/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 //This was needed since not even <map>, <vector> etc would resolve in eclipse.
```

Comment: including `/usr/include` doesn't change a thing. I tried to remove all other includes except the `/usr/include/c++/4.4` (otherwise the same problem occurs as you described).  But the syntax check does not complain about `unknown function` or something, but does think it is a syntax error. It confuses with a method declaration i think.

Comment: @Blue Did you make sure to update the index? If you hover over BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE, does it expand the macro?

Comment: yea it asked for rebuilding the index and i said yes. It is just showing the message syntax error (while hovering over the macro name). Interesting is that auto completion does not work either.

Comment: @Blue Alright, then I'm sorry, don't know what is wrong... Perhaps it is something they fixed in Helios (If you are using a previous version of eclipse that is). Or perhaps if you don't already choose to insert the include directory for all configurations and all languages (its two checkboxes on the "add include dir" when on the GNU c++ tab)... Could be that eclipse is viewing your files in C mode or something like that, maybe depending on fileextension.. But now I'm just guessing!

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense and autocompletion for C++ are pretty much impossible to get right in all cases. If the many macros used in Boost.Test confuse Eclipse, then perhaps you should find a cleaner unit test library. I can recommend [Catch](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2010/12/28/unit-testing-in-c-and-objective-c-just-got-easier.html), which has a cleaner and friendlier syntax, is header-only so it's much easier to set up, and doesn't rely on macros. It is under active development by another SO user.

Comment: HI Jalf, thanks for fast response, unfortunately using boost test suite was not my decision in this case.  The main problem is the `{}` part i think. Normal macros are OK. Adding `void` would satisfy the syntax check, but of course the code is invalid then. So maybe there is a chance to add this template to the syntax check.

Comment: Fair enough. I just know that Visual Studio acts funny with Boost.Test too (it autoindents wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well (but on a Mac system). Once I added the boost path to GNU C++ path options, I restarted my operating system and Eclipse doesn't tag BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE as an error any more.

Comment: questioner already stated that is what they have tried...this is not an answer